# Remote debugger: Print to PyCharm console, not remote terminal

Tags: debugging, pycharm

While remote debugging, if I type something into the PyCharm console, I want the output to go to the PyCharm console, not the remote terminal.

Typing into a local debug session:

[image]

Typing into a remote debug session: (The output goes to the remote server)

[image]

In the Remote Debug configuration I've tried both checking and unchecking the box "Redirect output to console"

[image]

[image]

Anyone know how to get output to print to the PyCharm console? I've tried both the latest EAP and 2017.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The issue was that I was clicking the button, but I wasn't modifying the code to use the correct `pydevd.settrace`

For output to be displayed in PyCharm it needed to be:

`pydevd.settrace(MyIPaddress, port=MyPort, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)`